# Polarizations on $M_{0,n}$ from Kapranov's quotient constructions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hilbert-schemes, projective-geometry

In Kapranov's marvelous paper *Chow quotients of Grassmannian I*, he proves that $\overline{M}_{0,n}$ is isomorphic to both the Hilbert quotient and Chow quotient $(\mathbb{P}^1)^n//\text{SL}_2$.  These quotients are by definition closed subvarieties of the Hilbert scheme and Chow variety (respectively) of $(\mathbb{P}^1)^n$.  Every Chow variety has a natural polarization coming from Chow forms, and Hilbert schemes have a family of polarizations.  Is it known what ample divisors on $\overline{M}_{0,n}$ we get by restricting these polarizations via Kapranov's construction?

Comment: There are some papers on this question. For starters, have you seen Alexeev and Swinarski's paper http://www.math.uga.edu/~davids/0812.0778.pdf?

Comment: Indeed, it is a nice paper.  The Chow quotient maps to all the GIT quotients, so the polarizations on the latter pull back to the former, namely M_{0,n}, but the Chow-GIT morphisms are contractions (for n > 6), so come from nef but not ample divisors.  So the Alexeev-Swinarski divisors cannot be the Hilbert or Chow polarizations (though perhaps their convex hull contains these ample divisors?...)